# Do you always use row.names=F in write.csv? Changing the default values inside R (base) functions

Tags: r, csv, defaults, write.table

Couldn't see a solution online but I thought this might be quite common.

- with `write.csv` I basically always have the argument `row.name` set to F. Is it possible to run a line once and update the default value of the argument for the rest of the session?
- I tried `paste <- paste(sep="")` which ran and returned no error but seemed to do nothing (and didn't destroy the `paste` function). This is another one, I always set `sep=""` with `paste`...
- like I always have `exclude=NULL` when I am using `table` so I can see the N/A values.

EDIT: So, I'm looking for a solution that will work for multiple functions if possible: `paste`, `write.csv`, `table` and other functions like these.

Comment: Just to mention it, for the case of `paste`, there's `paste0` where `sep = ""` by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
paste <- paste
formals(paste)$sep <- ""
```

This creates a new copy of `paste` in your workspace, and then modifies its default value for `sep` to `""`. Subsequent calls to `paste` will then use the modified copy, as it sits in front of the base environment in your search path.

Comment: Hmmm, this works for paste but not write.csv or table. Have updated question.

Comment: @nzcoops For `table` it's tricky (to be clear for set `NULL` as default). Try `formals(table)["exclude"] <- list(NULL)`. And `write.csv` is another story. I recommend to look at source of `write.csv` and `write.csv2` and try to write `write.csv3` to satisfy your needs.

Comment: Looking at the source to `write.csv` is likely to make you cry

Comment: @Anonymous_Downvotes: If you're going to down-vote, at least _hint_ at what makes the answer unhelpful so others can learn and/or the answer can be improved.

Answer (score 8):

`paste <- paste(sep="")` puts the output of `paste()` into an object named "paste".  You would need to do something like this instead.

```
paste <- function (..., sep = "", collapse = NULL) {
  base::paste(..., sep=sep, collapse=collapse)
}
```

You can also look at the [Defaults](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Defaults/) package for this sort of thing, but it doesn't currently work for two of your examples.

Comment: Hmm, I get a `Error: evaluation nested too deeply:` error with `setDefaults(paste, sep="")`.  I'll have to look into that...

Comment: Yeah, and the table part unfortunately doesn't work either. From the help for 'setDefaults' "Assigning NULL to any argument will remove the argument from the Defaults list."

Comment: With regard to the first part of your answer, why did you do what you did with collapse?

Comment: @nzcoops: I'm not sure what you mean by "why did you do what you did with collapse?"  All I did was create a new paste function in the global environment (which is higher on the search path than `package:base`) with the same arguments as `base::paste` but with a different default `sep` argument.

Comment: @joshua ...but in your example, you must call base::paste, not just paste! As it is written now, it causes infinite recursion...

Comment: @Tommy: Thanks; good catch. I really should test the code in my answers or simply refrain from answering after midnight...

Comment: @Joshua testing would be good ;) by the collapse question, I just mean did you have to do that? Or could you take out the collapse argument from both parts of that? Not being picky, just trying to understand :) I've updated the setDefaults part of your answer to since neither parts were working.

Comment: You could remove the collapse argument but I'm not sure if doing so would cause issues with other functions that use `paste`.  I'm working with the Defaults author to fix those issues.  The code is 4 years old, so it's due for some updating. ;-)